# How to solve an inverse of derivative ode

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods

How can I solve $$(\phi'(y))^{-1}=y^{-c_1}+y^{-c_2},$$ where $c_1,c_2$ are constants and $(\cdot)^{-1}$ is inverse? Since I have inverse of derivative and it's nonlinear I think it has to be done numerically but am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Does the ${-1}$ on the left indicate an inverse function, or a reciprocal?

Comment: No it's an inverse not a reciprocal

Comment: So we could alternatively write:$y=\phi'(y^{-c_1}+y^{-c_2})$? Or not?

Comment: I think so @Raskolnikov